# Country/State Picklist Management through trigger

Tags: triggercontext, country-and-state

I am trying to map country and state from one custom object say 'User Submission' to Account's billing address. My custom object has more values of countries and states than standard Country/State Picklist values in Data management in the org.
My requirement is to map the country and state value of custom object on insert to accounts billing address but if i add any value that does not exists in standard Country/State Picklist value then it should get added automatically over there or atleast it shouldn't throw any error to users while saving data in custom object.
otherwise it throws error:

We can't save this record because the

> “Populate User Submission Country and State” process failed. Give your
>   Salesforce admin these details. This error occurred when the flow
>   tried to update records: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION: There's a problem
>   with this state, even though it may appear correct. Please select a
>   state from the list of valid states.: Billing State/Province. You can
>   look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide. Error
>   ID: 1201921518-18725 (-2136315846)

Please suggest a solution how it can be achieved.

Comment: Can you post the screen shots of process builder or any other tool that you are using to achieve this?

Comment: What date did you hit that error id?